# How to connect to a SQLite DB with Agile Toolkit 4?

Tags: atk4, agiletoolkit

I'd like to use `SQLite3` with `Agile Toolkit`. I found it in the [documentation](http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/install/db) that the SQLite driver is included with `atk4`, but I couldn't find any examples of how to connect to a `SQLite DB.`

I tried to change the DB connection of the example applications shipped with `atk4` from `MySql` to SQLite using the format found in the [Pear:DB DSN documentation](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db.intro-dsn.php):

```
$config['dsn']='sqlite:////var/www/webdev/atk4_example.db';
```

but I keep getting the could not find driver PDO error:

```
Application Error: Database Connection Failed
BaseException, code: 0
Additional information:
    * PDO error: could not find driver
    * DSN: :host=;dbname=;charset=utf8

/var/www/webdev/atk4/lib/DB.php:94
```

The SQLite `PDO` driver seems to be installed correctly on the server. Both the phpinfo() and an `PHP/PDO/SQLite3` example page confirms that it works.

I'm learning Agile Toolkit, PHP and general web development, so I might be missing something trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try following syntax in your config.php?

```
$config['dsn']='sqlite://username:password@hostname/dbname';
```

Also please check if you have MySQL (yes, MySQL not SQLite) extension enabled in your php.ini. If not, then try to enable it and test again. If SQLite works with enabled MySQL extension then I guess I have found small bug in DB.php and could fix that.

Also it looks that you can pass DSN parameters in following format as array and maybe that's even better:

```
$config['dsn'] = array(
    'sqlite:host=hostname;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8',
    'username',
    'password'
);
```

Please try 2 solutions described above and let me know if they work.
I can't test that myself now because I'm not at my developing computer.

Comment: I couldn't get the string format to work, but the array format works with: `'sqlite:/absolute/path/to/sqlite.db'`.